# php authentication xzvxcvb

Tags: facebook, authentication

under the old system we just used to use
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$id = $facebook->require_login();

With the new outh system it seems you need to use php with javascript and using javascript to set top.location and then the returned url does not even work in ie because its too long....

Is there a simple php method for login that just returns the users id like what they used to have. This new outh method seems to complicate the hell outta something that used to be simple!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's guides on the changes you'll need to make linked from this summary page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/

If you're having a specific problem please edit your question and give the error message/code samples etc and maybe someone can help

Comment: Problem is when trying to use the oauth with ie you always end up with this error.

Webpage error details
Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 408
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://www.website.com/?state=44067c88ffd35453d0637b951fefdcd8&code=AQCBmtn4J3DCmDTG9X0SRDfsecjrNwmTTNBCf8Am1Fp4t8bT3yxxWnbhztoTV8dbAtrVa3bm_KSCqPZygvRtpaLOtp0ytM7Vklg9UaNxRilZwKReIJyVgHsED2wltR_MlQM-URR-UD_m4T-2k3AY_Ag39M5kqqAXNsy2sJNHXo2kSaOoRIs5Bq0Txw6Wrmjj6_amKd0OMX9Chgpxz-hiSqNe

Comment: Is that a server side or client side error? It's definitely not an error from Facebook - sounds like you haven't updated your code to support Oauth 2 but you enabled it anyway

Comment: IS ok that is not the error the problem is that I use javascript to get the id from facebook and then store it in a session now when you use redirect uri in the oauth method it redirects and loses the session so it needs to keep using the oauth to get the id which takes 2-3 seconds and makes all pages in the game run really slow..So how are others storing the players fb ID in their apps or is there a way to put it in a cookie and get it from the cookie??